# Why NSURLSessionUploadTask suspend method doesn't work and still retrieving data from the server?

Tags: resume, suspend, nsurlsessionuploadtask

this is my problem:

I have a registration *UIViewController* so the user can send his information via POST.

When the user taps "send", I instantiate a *NSURLSessionUploadTask* using the *NSURLSession uploadTaskWithRequest:fromData:completionHandler:* method and, if he wants to go back, he can taps the "back" button to go back to the previous *UIViewController*.

When the user taps the "back" button, an *UIAlertView* is shown just to ask the user if he's sure to cancel or not the registration. While the *UIAlertView* is shown, I mark the *NSURLSessionUploadTask* as suspended, using the *suspend* method, so the user can resume the registration if he isn't sure to go back. My problem is there: when I mark the task as suspended, it seems that the *NSURLSessionUploadTask* ignores it and stills doing the registration showing two *UIAlertViews*: the one which confirms the cancelation and the one having the server response.

Please, can you help me with this? I'm doing something wrong? Maybe there's something I'm ignoring. I can't suspend and resume it later :/

Doing the upload:

```
uploadTask = [sesion uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                                  fromData:data
                         completionHandler:^(NSData * data, NSURLResponse * response, NSError * error)
{
    ...
}];

[uploadTask resume];
```

Suspending the upload in the implementation of the "back" button:

```
if (uploadTask != nil) && (uploadTask == NSURLSessionTaskStateRunning))
{
    [uploadTask suspend];
}
```

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: No, I didn't find it... My "back" button just cancel the request without user confirmation.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The upload task just continues even when it's in the suspended state.